# Why is this RewriteCond to skip static file types not working?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I'm trying to use .htaccess rules to prevent certain static files from going through my PHP front controller, but it doesn't seem to work. The rules are as follows:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Don't try to pipe static files through php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(.*)\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|js|css|json|mp3|mp4|mov|ogv|ogg|ico)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/wrapper/index\.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /wrapper/index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

Despite the condition to skip files with certain extensions, if I hit `https://example.com/test.jpg` the request is still piped through `/wrapper/index.php` every time.

I tried this variation just to test, and it didn't work either:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|js|css|json|mp3|mp4|mov|ogv|ogg|ico) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/wrapper/index\.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /wrapper/index.php [L]
```

There's nothing telling in the Apache error log. Maybe my mind is just weary from a long day at work, but I haven't been able to identify the flaw in my rewrite condition. Thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through grueling trial and error I identified the problem, and I don't yet quite understand the mechanism. This script was a wrapper for a Wordpress site that had previously been working fine. Evidently something caused the `/wp-content/uploads` directory to lose the `execute` bit for `group` and `world`. Once I chmodded to 755, this .htaccess rule began working again.

I don't quite understand how or why that interfered with an htaccess rule, but I'm happy to be back in service.

Answer (score 0):

First condition has an error - it will skip all files that **begin** with dot, following anything and ending in extensions you wrote. Just lose ^* in it, like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.+)\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|js|css|json|mp3|mp4|mov|ogv|ogg|ico)$ [NC]
```

Comment: Thanks for the thought, but I am sad to report that your revised condition produced no change.

Comment: I sincerely appreciate the effort, but it still made no difference.

Comment: Well, updated answer was actually tested (with addition of adding "txt" extension to static files list) and it works as expected. Is that whole contents of your .htaccess file?

Comment: I did have some other lines in my .htaccess, but I deleted all other lines as a test, and it didn't help. I'm beginning to wonder if it's some server configuration issue. When I test it on my local dev environment it's fine, but on the live server it fails. The rewrite mod must be on, because the RewriteRule works, just not the RewriteCond.